# zk - java textbox validation before fileupload

Tags: java, validation, upload, zk

I have a textbox and a button with upload = true attribute component in zk framework and i would like to control textbox value, if it is empty or not, before upload dialog pops up. I tried onChange event on textbox to disable and enable button according to value The problem is button is not enabled/disabled before clicking to somewhere else. That is if i write some text in textbox and after click on button, it still remains diabled. After second click it gets activated.

Comment: and also if i clear text while button is enabled and after click button dialog pops up.

Answer (score 1):

You should use **onChanging** instead of **onChange**. Also, only ZK-side solution is working correctly but ZK + Java side solution is not working what you want.

ZK-Side solution ( **working** )

```
<zk>
  <textbox>
    <attribute name="onChanging">
      if ( event.getValue().length() > 0 )
        but.setDisabled( false );
      else
        but.setDisabled( true );
    </attribute>
  </textbox>
  <button id="but" disabled="true" upload="true,maxsize=300" label="Up" />
</zk>
```

ZK + Java solution ( **not working properly** )

### ZK

```
<window title="Hello World!!" border="normal" width="200px" apply="com.UploadFile">

<textbox id="value" />

<button id="but" disabled="true" upload="true,maxsize=300" label="Up" />

</window>
```

### JAVA

```
public class UploadFile extends GenericForwardComposer<Window> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Textbox value;
    private Button but;

    public void onChanging$value() {
        if ( value.getValue().length() > 0 )
            but.setDisabled( false );
          else
            but.setDisabled( true );
    }

    public void onClick$but() {
        alert(value.getValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your response to include an explanation: @IanDecks should switch from using `onChange` to `onChanging`.

Comment: Thanks for the java part. Worked for Mvc approach.

Answer (score 0):

Even if this

```
<zk>
  <textbox>
    <attribute name="onChanging">
      if ( event.getValue().length() > 0 )
        but.setDisabled( false );
      else
        but.setDisabled( true );
    </attribute>
  </textbox>
  <button id="but" disabled="true" upload="true,maxsize=300" label="Up" />
</zk>
```

is working, this is not recomanded for production. See [this](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/Overture/Technology_Guidelines#When_to_use_zscript).

My solution

```
public class MyClass extends SelectorComposer<Window> {
   @Wire
   private Button btn;

   @Listen("onChanging = #myTextBoxID")
   public void onChanging(ChangeingEvent ev) {
      btn.setDisabled( ev.getValue().isEmpty() );
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have a `Textbox`, `Combobox`, `Spinner` or another component used to control something like the enabled/disabled property of a `Button`, a common approach is to use the `onChanging` event of such component. ZK treats this event in a special way.

So we have:

```
<textbox id="myTextbox" />
<button id="myButton" disabled="true" />
```

All the common tries to get the value in a MVC environment, as already stated, won't work.

```
@Listen("onChanging = #myTextbox")
public void onChangingTextbox(Event event){

   String byGetText = myTextbox.getText(); //Will give you the old value
   String byGetValue = myTextbox.getValue(); //Will still give the old value
   String byEvent = event.getValue(); //Yet another way to get the old value

   if(!byGetText.equals("")) myButton.setDisabled(false)
   else myButton.setDisabled(true);

   if(!byGetValue.equals("")) myButton.setDisabled(false)
   else myButton.setDisabled(true);

   if(!byEvent.equals("")) myButton.setDisabled(false)
   else myButton.setDisabled(true);

   //All of the above won't work when the Textbox is cleared since the 
   //referred value is the old value.
}
```

The solution is in the event. We must use `InputEvent` instead of `Event` to get the new value:

```
@Listen("onChanging = #myTextbox")
public void onChangingTextbox(InputEvent event){

   String byEvent = event.getValue(); //This will give you the new value

   //This control will behave as wanted
   if(!byEvent.equals("")) myButton.setDisabled(false)
   else myButton.setDisabled(true);

}
```

The `onChanging` event is fired before the assignment of the new value to the `Textbox` value field and therefore, when fetched on the event handler, you get the old value. Also in the `Event` class the new value field is private and unreachable, thus the `getValue()` method returns the old value. Instead in the `InputEvent` the new value is preferred when `getValue()` is called.